# How can I make a shortcut to search using Google Scholar from the address bar in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, search, shortcuts

I don't like having to navigate to http://scholar.google.com/ before I type my search.

Comment: How to add search engines to Chrome: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95653?hl=en
Put a `%s` in the URL where your search term is supposed to go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's very easy. Just follow these steps.

1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
2. Select Settings and find the "Search" section.
3. Click "Manage Search engines".
4. Now add the following URL: **`http://scholar.google.ch/scholar?hl=en&q=%s`**
5. Click the Make default button that appears at the end of the row.

Now you can search directly from the omnibar in the google scholar-section.

Comment: If you can also leave your default search as a regular Google search if you want. After you've done the above steps, you can follow what Xorbyte describes, i.e. start typing "scholar" until the URL appears, then hit tab and input your search.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting but somewhat hidden feature in Chrome is that it actually siphons visited search engines continuously and provides easy access to their search URLs via the browser preferences.

As an example, right now I went to Google Scholar and did a dummy search ("test"), and directly afterwards I can go to "Settings" → "Manage search engines…",  and now "scholar.google.com" is in the "Other search engines" list with the correct search URL already filled in. The second column represents the keyword, so just click it and enter "gs" or whatever you feel comfortable with, click "Done" and it is indeed done.

It's not difficult to manually add engines for that matter, but this is a nice but not really advertised feature. I follow the "unstable" branch of Google Chrome, but this is not a new function, so it might very well already be in the stable branch.

Answer (score 2):

If you type the first few letters of the site in the omnibar (say, <kbd>sch</kbd>) and tab, the omnibar will change to say *Search scholar.google.com* and you can type in your text and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to have it executed.

This works with many other search engines that you may not have added, like Wikis etc; once you visit the site, Chrome remembers it for future use.

Comment: I just get a link to go to `scholar.google.com`, not an ability to search within it.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that using duckduckgo you can navigate directly from your search bar using bangs. https://duckduckgo.com/bang 
for example to access google.scholar just type

```
!gsch search engine
```