# How to create a shortcut to search Google Scholar from the address bar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, search

Just want to create open-search queries to search instantly from the search bar for *google scholar*. This is easy with [Brave and Chrome, using Open Search queries](https://superuser.com/questions/650801/how-can-i-make-a-shortcut-to-search-using-google-scholar-from-the-address-bar-in). This has been possible with FireFox in the past. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

**you can do "add search engine" here: https://chaim-chv.github.io/scholar/**

this website can add the google scholar search engine to your firefox browser.

just click on three vertical dots at the address bar, click "add search engine" and you can search in scholar right from the address bar, and even you can set it as default search engine as well.

For anyone wondering: I built this site (just set up the search engine and put it in as a <link> tag in the index.html file)

**enjoy learn & discovering!**

Answer (score 1):

There's a Google Scholar search engine add-on that was last updated about three months ago. I just tested it, and it that seems to do what you want. It's at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-scholar-search-engine/?src=search

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to attain this:

1. Easy Method:
   Add `http://scholar.google.ch/scholar?hl=en&q=%s` as a bookmark and add your keyword.

[![Bookmark property][1]][1]

2. *Medium/Hard method:
   You can create your own Firefox search @[https://mycroftproject.com/submitos.html][2]
   Google Scholar already had some crowdsourced search engines.
   [https://mycroftproject.com/search-engines.html?name=google+scholar][3]*

Just learned that Firefox deprecated this method in early 2020.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyBtF.png
[2]: https://mycroftproject.com/submitos.html
[3]: https://mycroftproject.com/search-engines.html?name=google%20scholar

Answer (score -1):

- First go to https://scholar.google.com
- Then click the Three vertical dots at the address bar.
- Then click add search engine.

Now the logo of scholar.google.com will appear at the address bar with other search engine logos.

Comment: There's no "add search engine" option after clicking on the three vertical dots at the address bar.